# array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Tags: laravel, pagination

I'm trying to paginate big data form the database, but one problem commes form this funciton who is **array_keys()**, the error says **an expected array in parameter 1 but object given**.

the other data paginated fine, it's just the file's keys(the header), because when I remove this code of header(file keys) it works fine. So the error commes from this part of code:

```
   <thead>  

    @if ($arrkeys= array_keys($products[0])) 
        @foreach ($arrkeys as $keys)  
            <th>{{$key}}</th>
        @endforeach  
    @endif 

   </thead>
```

This is pagination function code in the controller:

```
 public function indexPagination()
    { 
        $products = Product::all() ;
        $products = Product::paginate(5);   
        //$paginateProducts = Product::paginate(10);

        return view ('inventory.layout', compact('products'));
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in this line of code `$arrkeys= array_keys($products[0]` ? what keys do you want?

Comment: I'm trying to show all csv products keys or (csv fiel header) by looping  through $arrKeys.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function indexPagination()
{ 
    $products = Product::all() ;
    $products = Product::paginate(5);   
    //$paginateProducts = Product::paginate(10);
    return view ('inventory.layout', compact('products')->toArray());
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, comes another problem says (Call to a member function toArray() on array)